# Ignore codeowners completely

Tags: github, github-codeowners

I am looking to figure out if there is a way to **ignore** *CODEOWNERS* file (without really deleting the file itself) and stop auto tagging reviewers from *CODEOWNERS* file.

I disabled the check to **"Require review from Code Owners"** but did not have any luck.

[Branch rule to disable review from code owners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB7DK.png)